# Will using super(type, instance) call the derived version of an embedded method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, delegation

If I instance a derived class:

```
class ContactReports(CleanUpReports):

    def do_batch(self, batchfile):
        super(CleanUpReports,self).do_batch(batchfile)

    def extend(self, rpt):
        self.specialized_processing(rpt)
```

But the parent class also has an extend function defined like so:

```
class CleanUpReports:
    ...

    def do_batch(self, batchfile):
        with open(batchfile) as f:
             for rpt in f:
                self.extend(rpt)

    def extend(self, rpt):
       self.default_processing(rpt)
```

Will the delegated `do_batch()` method call the parent version of `extend()` or the derived instance version of `extend()?`

How can I ensure the delegated version of `do_batch()` calls the derived version of `extend()`?

Comment: If `self` is the derived instance, `self.extend` will bind to the derived implementation. You can verify this by putting a couple of simple prime statements in your methods to tell you which one is being called

Comment: You probably meant `super(ContactReports,self)` not `super(CleanUpReports,self)` - the former way skips over some stuff in mro, which is probably causing some confusion to bring this question in the first place. Or just use `super()`.

Comment: Ok, it often takes someone else's eyes.  Sure enough should be `super(ContactReports, self)` in the code.  Also, super() does work and binds to the derived method as desired.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it will call the implementation of the derived or child class (`ContactReports` in this case).

To verify this I am going to do a small test simplifying the code a little bit and also add a new method called `` in the parent class:

```
class CleanUpReports:
  def do_batch(self):
    print("do_batch from parent class")

  def extend(self):
    print("extend from parent class")

  def func_only_in_parent(self):
    print("func_only_in_parent from parent class")

class ContactReports(CleanUpReports):
  def do_batch(self):
    print("do_batch from child class")
  
  def extend(self):
    print("extend from child class")
```

When instantiating an object from the child class, you get this:

```
child_instance = ContactReports()
child_instance.do_batch()
child_instance.extend()
child_instance.func_only_in_parent()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> do_batch from child class
>>> extend from child class
>>> func_only_in_parent from parent class
```

And as an addition, if you instantiate an object from the parent class you get this.

```
parent_instance = CleanUpReports()
parent_instance.do_batch()
parent_instance.extend()
parent_instance.func_only_in_parent()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> do_batch from parent class
>>> extend from parent class
>>> func_only_in_parent from parent class
```

Comment: Excellent example. Would be nice if Section 9.5 in the Python.org Tutorial included an example with super().  The built-in function documentation for super() is pretty opaque too.  I see https://bugs.python.org/issue40343  which Dominick V. has opened on just such a complaint.  Thanks again.